# What is the exact meaning of "to an extent"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the exact meaning of the phrase "to an extent" in the following sentence?

> A country’s future prosperity depends, to an extent, upon the quality
> of the education of its people.

Which one explains what the phrase means, more accurately?

1. It reduces the importance of the quality of the education. I mean if we omit this phrase, the sentence will put more emphasis on education.
2. It does not reduce the importance of education. It just mentions that a country’s future prosperity depends also on other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means *to some extent* or *partially.* I don't think your two senses are mutually exclusive. If the phrase were omitted, the sentence would mean that the quality of education was the *only* thing that the country's prosperity depended on. The intelligent reader would understand your second interpretation; that there must be other things which will also make a contribution.